# Is there a way to make a object subscriptable?

Tags: python, oop

I have an example class:

```
class collection:
    def __init__(self, itemArray):
        self.itemArray = itemArray
        self.max = len(itemArray)


    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index < self.max:
            result = self.itemArray[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

My goal is to access the variable `self.itemArray` without having to explicitly use `collection.itemArray` from outside the class. I want to be able to loop over the object by making it an iterable, which is why I have `__iter__` and `__next__`.

I want to mimic the behaviour that string types employs, ie.

```
stringVar = "randomTextString"
stringVar[indexVal]
```

Attempting this with a object would not work as it will raise a TypeError because objects aren't subscriptable.

I just need someone to point me in the right direction. I looked at the python docs for a solution but I didn't seem to find anything.

Comment: Override `__getitem__`

Comment: I was surprised not to find a good duplicate for this question. I did find some people who already knew how to do this and wanted to expand upon it; but perhaps in the future I will be referring *other* questions *here*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` magics:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return self.itemArray[idx]

def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
    self.itemArray[idx] = val
```

Comment: For what it's worth: if you provide `__getitem__` as well as `__len__` (which seems like something you probably want to have anyway), the standard library [`collections.abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) can generate a `__next__` and `__iter__` for you.

Comment: If I wanted to append or use other array methods on ```self.itemArray``` , without having to explicity using ```objCollection.itemArray.append("val")``` . And just do ```objCollection,append("val")``` . Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @user5423 Depends on your goals - if you just want to expand lists, make `collection` inherit from `list`, and for each customized function call its origin `super().function(args...) `. You wouldn't even need the other methods you implemented.  Note that `list`'s `__init__` signature is same as yours, with `itemArray` defaulting to empty list.

Comment: @user5423 see what I described above [here](https://tio.run/##XY3LCsMgEEX3foW7OFDcpO2i0C8JQQYzIcKgonaRrzfmQQu9y3vuI65lCb6v1TLmLG1gJltc8IpdLvASsmmiWRrjvCvGqEw83ySmhOuFd@2uPkz5PuEPfSIlBfq7cHaFENiyf4@qW4g5dNB4TM4XhcN9BIFDP7b0U6DGGMlP6gFX4Ki50j4QAGrdAA)